# Fourier transform $f(x) = cosx$ , $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: fourier-transform

> Fourier transform $f(x) = \cos{x}$ , $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$
>
> $f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \cos{x},  & \text{$x \in [-\pi,\pi]$} \\[2ex]
> 0, & \text{else}
> \end{cases}$

Well, after some calculations I got to

$\frac{1}{2\pi}(\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi w)}{1-w} + \frac{\sin(\pi+\pi w)}{1+w})$,

I don't know how to play with the numerator so I get to this:

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{2w\sin(\pi w)}{1-w^2}$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\sin(\pi - \pi w) = \sin (\pi w)$ and $\sin(\pi + \pi w) = -\sin(\pi w)$

Comment: @OpenBall Still didn't get to the answer.

Comment: Really?! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @OpenBall Just kidding. I guess it's the same trick with $cos(\pi - \pi w) = cos(\pi w)$.. And thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can represent $f(x)$ by

$$f(x)=H(\pi-|x|)\cos(x)$$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

The Fourier Transform of $\cos(x)$ is

$$\mathcal{F}[\cos(x)](\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\delta(\omega-1)+\delta(\omega+1)\right)$$

and the Fourier Transform of $H(\pi-|x|)$ is easily calculated:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[H(\pi-|x|)](\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(\pi-|x|)e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
&=-\frac{2}{2i\omega\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[e^{-i\omega\pi}-e^{i\omega\pi}\right]\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\sin(\pi\omega)}{\omega}
\end{align}

Now, by the Convolution Theorem, the Fourier Transform of the product of two functions is given by the convolution of their Fourier Transforms:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}[H(\pi-|x|)\cos(x)](\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\delta(s-\omega-1)+\delta(s-\omega+1)\right)\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{s}ds\\
&=\frac{\sin(\pi(\omega-1))}{\omega-1}+\frac{\sin(\pi(\omega+1))}{\omega+1}
\end{align}